# How to organize fields in dataframe by repetition and drop duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this

```
id phone1 phone2 
1  300    301
1  303    300
1  300    303
2  400    401
```

Want this

```
id phone1 phone2 phone3
1  300    303    301
2  400    401
```

I have tried group by id and column phone1, apply count function, iterate over it adding to a list verifying if is already there the id and phone and sum the third column, and do the same thing with phone2 in the same list

After it reorganize the dataframe iterating the list but this is so slow with the millions of data that i have to proccess

```
dataframe1 = dataframe.groupby(['id', 'phone1']).count().reset_index()
dataframe2 = dataframe.groupby(['id', 'phone2']).count().reset_index()
```

result to add in a list

```
id phone1 phone2
1  300    2    
1  303    1
2  401    1

id phone1 phone2
1  300    1   
1  301    1
1  303    1
2  400    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this via grouping and sorting groups by count.

First, collect phones from each phone column:

```py
phone_columns = df.columns[1:]
df["phone_list"] = df[phone_columns].apply(list, axis=1)
df = df.groupby("id").agg(phone_list_agg=("phone_list", lambda x: list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x))))

                                        phone_list_agg
id                                                   
1   [300, 301, 303, 300, 300, 303, 800, 800, 800, 800]
2                                           [400, 401]
```

Then, group phones and sort by count:

```py
df["phone_tuples"] = df.apply(lambda x: [(k,len(list(g))) for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(x["phone_list_agg"]))], axis=1)
df = df.drop("phone_list_agg", axis=1)
df["phone_tuples"] = df.apply(lambda x: sorted(x["phone_tuples"], key=lambda y:y[1], reverse=True), axis=1)

                                phone_tuples
id                                          
1   [(800, 4), (300, 3), (303, 2), (301, 1)]
2                       [(400, 1), (401, 1)]
```

Finally, unpack tuples into separate columns:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[y[0] for y in x] for x in df["phone_tuples"]], index=df.index)
df.columns = [f"phone{i}" for i in range(1, len(df.columns) + 1)]
df = df.reset_index()

   id  phone1  phone2  phone3  phone4
0   1     800     300   303.0   301.0
1   2     400     401     NaN     NaN
```

You can fill NaN above with some value (for ex. -1) and convert float to int using following:

```py
df = df.fillna(-1).astype(int)
```

Sample dataset used:

```py
data=[
(1,300,301),
(1,303,300),
(1,300,303),
(2,400,401),
(1,800,800),
(1,800,800),
]

columns = ["id", "phone1", "phone2"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
```

Comment: This is useful, thanks
Note: with nan values ​​between data in dataframe the code won't work

Comment: What are your rules to handle NaN numbers? For example, if the rule is to fill NaN with "-1", then you can use `df = df.fillna(-1).astype(int)`.

Comment: Updated answer with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can `melt` to reshape the phone columns to rows, then remove the duplicates per group. Finally, `pivot` to reshape back to wide format.

```
out = (df
   .melt('id')
   .drop_duplicates(['id', 'value'])
   .assign(col=lambda d: d.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1))
   .pivot_table(index='id', columns='col', values='value', fill_value=pd.NA)
   .astype('Int64') # optional
   .add_prefix('phone')
   .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
   id  phone1  phone2  phone3
0   1     300     303     301
1   2     400     401    <NA>
```

Comment: Have you tested it? Feedback would be appreciated since you opened a new question

Comment: Hello mozway your suggestion works with the example data, but when i add two rows more with phone1 and phone 2 in 888 for example

id phone1 phone2
1 300         301
1 303         300
1 300         303
2 400     401
1 800         800
1 800         800

The result should be the 800 in the first row for id 1, because is the more repeated, but isnt.  maybe I didn't make myself clear. Anyways thank you for your answer mozway :p